# Issue the checkBox and select the action not done

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, checkbox, datatables

I  have Issue when i select the action on select and coched all checkbox and click on ok not do anything  this datatables contains the checkbox my following code :

```
function toggleChecks(obj) {
    $('.case').prop('checked', obj.checked);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    tablecontact = $('#table-contact').dataTable({
        "info": true,
        "aoColumns": [{
            "sTitle": "<input type='checkbox' name='selectedContact[]' id='selectAll'  onclick='toggleChecks(this);' ></input>",
            "mDataProp": null,
            "sWidth": "20px",
            "sDefaultContent": "<input type='checkbox' id="
            table - selected - <?= $this - > idContact; ?> " value='<?=$this->idContact ;?>' class='case'></input>", "bSortable": false
        },
        null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
            'sDom': 'lTfr<"clearfix">tip',
            'oTableTools': {
            'aButtons': []
        },
            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) { //lien edition
            $('td:eq(8)', nRow).html('<a href="/<?=Zend_Registry::get('
            Zend_Locale ')->getLanguage();?>/admin/contact-management/updatecontact/idContact/' + aData[0] + '"><b>' + aData[8] + '</b></a>');
            return nRow;
        },
    });

    var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table);
    $(tt.fnContainer()).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper');
```

and the select the action when i selected all checkbox i want do action and click ok but not work

```
<select name="table-action" id="table-action" class="small">
    <option value="0">Appliquer à la sélection</option>
    <option value="unsetemailnotification">UnsetEmailNotification</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="small" id="actionContact">Ok</button>
```

on my controller the following code :

```
public function setemailnotificationAction()
    {
        $ids = explode(';', $this->_request->getParam('listId',0));
        $contact = new Admin_Model_DbTable_Contact();
        if(!empty($ids))
        {
            foreach($ids as $id)
            {
                if(!$contact->setemailnotificationContact(intval($id)))
                {
                    echo json_encode(array(
                            "response" => "false",
                            "errorMessage" => "Il y a eu une erreur dans l'activation de l'email notification: ". $id
                    ));
                    exit();
                }
            }

            ));
            exit();
        }

        exit();
    }
```

and i do that on .phtml :

```
$('#actionContact').click(function(){

var confirmAction = true;
var listId = '';   
var selectAction = $("#table-action").val();
$(".sorting_1").find(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    if(listId.length == 0){
        listId +=  $(this).val();
    }else{
        listId += ";" + $(this).val();
    }           
});

});
```

Comment: Please include more details. What erros do you get? What version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: In `var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table);` the variable `table` is not defined anyplace that I can see.

Comment: when i select the méthod and clik ok nothing happened i need to run the function selected

Comment: Did you fix the issue I mentioned? What else have you done, errors, something? "Nothing happens" is not descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a bit, but I think this is what you're looking to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zfg3r4j6/

```
function toggleChecks(obj) {
    //$('.case').prop('checked', obj.checked);
    $.each($(".case"), function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(this).prop("checked", "");
        } else {
            $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
        }
    });
}
```

Also would switch away from `onclick='toggleChecks(this);'` to a JQuery solution:

```
$("#selectAll").on("change", function () {
    toggleChecks($(this));
});
```

Not sure what you wanted to do with `<select>`, so add more info, and we can help.

**EDIT:**

I suspect you are following this example: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/checkbox.html ?

Comment: Could be reduced to $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).is(":checked"));

Comment: when i clik on ok  nothing happened i need help please

Comment: It is not clear what your function is doing when you click Ok button. Please provide more details. What is it going to do, what do you expect, what errors do you get? Cannot just say it's not working, that is not helpful.